# ActionScript 3: Know the instance name of a hit movieClip

Tags: string, actionscript-3, instance, movieclip, hit

My circle_mc is draggable. Then when it hit another movieclip on stage, is there any way to show up the instance name hit by the circle_mc?

is it possible this way...

```
var theInstanceName:String = circle_mc.hitTestObject()
```

Any solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider a situation, if your `circle_mc` hit a dozen of instances. What do you want to receive?

Comment: I want all of those instance names... or just the last hit movieclip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should perform a hit test against the various objects, for example, assuming you had an array `objects` of movieclips and wanted to return another array `collidingMovieclips`:

```
var collidingObjects:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if(circle_mc.hitTestObject(objects[i])) {
        collidingObjects.push(objects[i]);
    }
}
```

You could quite easily add `objects[i].name` to return the instance names instead, but I'm not sure why you'd want to.

Note that this is by no means the most efficient method, but may be sufficient to meet your needs.